# Конструктор <vector>

Tags: c++, классы, перегрузка-операторов, конструктор, вектор

Хочу написать конструктор класса, который в качестве параметра принимает статический массив (указатель на 1 элемент) и инициализирует вектор внутри класса этим массивом:

```
class A
{ 
  public:
    explicit A(int x[]):v(x,x+sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)) {} // или (int* x)
  private:
    vector<int> v;
};
```

Не работает... В чём проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Параметр вашего конструктора имеет тип `int *`. Поэтому выражение

```
sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)
```

эквивалентно выражению

```
sizeof( int * )/sizeof( int )
```

И может равняться либо 2, если размер указателя равен, например, 8 байтам, а размер объекта типа `int` равен 4 байтам, либо 1, если данные размеры совпадают.

Лучше объявить два перегруженных конструктора.

Первый конструктор может быть определен как

```
A( const int *first, const int *last ) : v( first, last ) {}
```

а второй конструктор может быть определен либо как

```
A( const int *first, size_t n ) : v( first, first + n ) {}
```

либо использовать делегирующий конструктор

```
A( const int *first, size_t n ) : A( first, first + n ) {}
```

Также вы можете объявить шаблонный конструктор, как, например,

```
template <size_t N>
A( const int ( &a )[N] ) : v( a, a + N ) {}
```

Вот демонстрационная программа, в которой показаны все три способа вызова конструкторов класса

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A
{
    A( const int *first, const int *last ) : v( first, last ) {}
    A( const int *first, size_t n ) : v( first, first + n ) {}    
    template <size_t N>
    explicit A( const int ( &a )[N] ) : v( a, a + N ) {}

    std::vector<int> v;
};

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    A a1( a, a + sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    for ( int x : a1.v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    A a2( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    for ( int x : a1.v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    A a3( a );

    for ( int x : a1.v ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Можете пояснить про "делегирующий" конструктор?

Comment: @FMIG Вы можете в списке инициализации одного конструктора вызывать другой конструктор, тем самым ему делегируя работу по созданию объекта. В этом случае список инициализации должен состоять только из вызова конструктора.

Comment: Понял, а ещё: имеет ли смысл ставить спецификатор explicit?

Comment: @FMIG Для шаблонного конструктора можете использовать спецификатор explicit, так как данный конструктор имеет один параметр.

Answer (score 3):

В параметрах функции, в отличие от объявлений массива, `int x[]` вырождается в `int* x`, т.е. ничем не отличается от обычного указателя. (Параметры `int x[5]` или `int x[6]` также вырождаются `int* x`).

Поэтому надо использовать шаблон и ссылку на массив.

```
class A
{ 
  public:
    template<size_t N>
    explicit A(int (&x)[N]) : v(x, x + N) {}
  private:
    vector<int> v;
};
```

Ссылка `int (&x)[N]` не теряет количество элементов в массиве.

Comment: Разве в данном случае понятие "указатель" не равносилен "итератор"?

Comment: @FMIG В каком-то смысле равносилен, но какое это в данном случае имеет значение?

Comment: @kff Вот именно. Но abyx уже убрал эту строку из своего ответа)